# In-App Billing: Getting User is not eligible to purchase

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I know about all the user account specification and where to register for the test account in developer console.

Question: To which user this message is referring?
The user that is currently logged in google play on device?
if yes. Why it is giving the same message even if there aren't any users logged in google play?
There is many google accounts on this device. maybe this message is referring to the default one. how to change it. (the default one: is when u clear google play data, then open google play it will force you to log in with).

When you are not logged in google play. why when you test in-app billing it does not ask for log in??

Thanks.

Comment: When you are not logged in google play. why when you test in-app billing it does not ask for log in??

Comment: your default google account will be used for purchasing... If you are unauthorized to buy items just make sure you added your device to the list of the test devices. If you do this, you will be able to purchase after some minutes!

Comment: how I can add my device? default is the one I am currently using with google play?

Comment: how to login with my tester account?

Comment: You default google account is the one you have registered at the first time on your device, I guess. Then you have to put that e-mail address on the list of "test devices" of your google play developer account

Comment: yes, that's true. thanks it worked. now I have another problem I need a valid visa. :)

Comment: go and enter that as an answer.

Comment: Glad to help hasan. Take a look at my answer. I made reference to your VISA problem and I explain there how you can resolve it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your default Google Account will be used for purchasing... If you are unauthorized to buy items just make sure you add your device to the list of the test devices.

You default Google Account is the one you have registered at the first time on your device, I guess. Then you have to put that e-mail address on the list of "test devices" of your Google Play Developer Account and you will be able to purchase after some minutes.

If you want to use your own products you will need a real VISA to purchase. Alternatively, you can use *static* product IDs to purchase with a fake credit card.

Take a look at the [Testing with static responses](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static) Google's official documentation to know when and what IDs you can use for testing purposes.